# Why I get GitHub action/cache@v3 download problem?

Tags: github, ssl-certificate, github-actions

Im running Selfhosted GitHub runner on AWS EC2 instance.

I have step in GitHub workflow:

```
- name: Cache Maven dependencies
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request' || github.event.pull_request.merged == true
        id: cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.m2/repository
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-
```

During execution of this workflow I get this error:

```
Download action repository 'actions/cache@v3' (SHA:88522ab9f39a2ea568f7027eddc7d8d8bc9d59c8)
Warning: Failed to download action 'https://api.github.com/repos/actions/cache/tarball/88522ab9f39a2ea568f7027eddc7d8d8bc9d59c8'. Error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Warning: Back off 17.362 seconds before retry.
Error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
```

If I go directly to my GitHub self hosted runner and I execute wget or curl to the link, I get this error:

```
ubuntu@ip-11-224-36-17:~$ wget https://api.github.com/repos/actions/cache/tarball/88522ab9f39a2ea568f7027eddc7d8d8bc9d59c8
--2023-07-27 08:37:25--  https://api.github.com/repos/actions/cache/tarball/88522ab9f39a2ea568f7027eddc7d8d8bc9d59c8
Resolving api.github.com (api.github.com)... 140.82.121.6
Connecting to api.github.com (api.github.com)|140.82.121.6|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I added something like this to my openssl.cnf file:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init [openssl_init] ssl_conf = ssl_sect [ssl_sect] system_default = system_default_sect [system_default_sect] Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
```

and it works

But now I have other issue during workflow execution:

```
:~$ wget https://api.github.com/repos/actions/cache/tarball/88522ab9f39a2ea568f7027eddc7d8d8bc9d59c8
--2023-07-27 13:40:10--  https://api.github.com/repos/actions/cache/tarball/88522ab9f39a2ea568f7027eddc7d8d8bc9d59c8
Resolving api.github.com (api.github.com)... 140.82.121.5
Connecting to api.github.com (api.github.com)|140.82.121.5|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://codeload.github.com/actions/cache/legacy.tar.gz/88522ab9f39a2ea568f7027eddc7d8d8bc9d59c8 [following]
--2023-07-27 13:40:11--  https://codeload.github.com/actions/cache/legacy.tar.gz/88522ab9f39a2ea568f7027eddc7d8d8bc9d59c8
Resolving codeload.github.com (codeload.github.com)... 140.82.121.9
Connecting to codeload.github.com (codeload.github.com)|140.82.121.9|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

Comment: I added something like this to my openssl.cnf file: openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation  and it works

Answer (score 0):

Update openSSL libtrary in your system. Use this command if you are using ubuntu.

```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install openssl
```

If updating doesn't work then enable legacy renegotiation for the SSL connection by opening /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf file and adding this line of code in the end of file.

```
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

Create new configuration file after saving the file. use this line of code

```
sudo nano /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

No w after adding the following piece of code in the file, save it and download it again

```
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

Now run following command to synchronize the time with NTP (Network Time Protocol)

```
sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

At the end run **'wget'** or **'curl'** again to check whether the SSL connection error is resolved or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your self hosted runner you can try to do the following checks on your machine:

```
openssl version

openssl s_client -connect github.com:443 -tls1_2
```

From there you will have information on how to proceed to resolve this SSL conflict, maybe it's time to update your openssl client.